# Xamarin iOS Azure Storage Dependency

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-storage

I am trying to use blob storage on a Xamarin iOS App, I have added the Windows Azure Nuget package and am getting the following error:

> .../CSC: Error CS1705: Assembly `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' depends on`System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version number than referenced assembly `System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' (CS1705)

My System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives package is on version 4.0.1 and I can find no other references in the project to this or the 4.0.0.0 version.  Both my WindowsAzure.Storage package and the System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives package are up to date. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which version of Xamarin are you using? I somewhat recall running into this error, but once I updated to Xamarin 4.1 everything started working.

Comment: I am using Xamarin.iOS Version: 9.8.2.22

Comment: Ok that's the same version I have. Please use the latest Azure Storage library (7.2) as well. I recently created a sample app on Visual Studio that worked with Xamarin 4.1 (which has Xamarin.iOS 9.8) - https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.1/#Xamarin.vs4.1.0 and Azure Storage Client Library 7.2 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage

Comment: I am using Azure Storage 7.2.  I cannot find any reference to the assembly System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives v4.0.0, only 4.0.1.0, which the error states is the correct version.

Comment: The 'DownloadTextAsync' function works on the CloudBlockBlob but all the other Download functions such as 'DownloadToStreamAsync' throw the dependency error.

Comment: Can you also try updating your packages. I also remember updating Microsoft.Data.Edm to latest version (v5.7) and that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a preview version of Azure Storage with Xamarin. I switched to

> v7.1.3-preview

by entering the value manually in the packages.config file and restarted Xamarin Studio, now it all builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Azure Storage that works properly with Xamarin is 4.4.0-preview, as mentioned in Azure documentation.

Comment: How do you install this version?  Only version I can get through Nuget is 7.2.

Comment: @Carl Nuget includes dozens of non-preview versions of WindowsAzure.Storage, the earliest version being 1.6.0. I am unsure if you know how to get old version from Nuget, for installed packages it is a dropdown box next to the 'Update' buddon. Other than that as this is pre-release you must also check 'Include prelelase' checkbox.

Comment: The only one I can see is 3.2.0-preview.  Xamarin Studio doesn't have the option to change the version for installed packages, only 'Update', 'Remove' or 'Refresh'.

Comment: @Carl I was reporting on what is available in Visual Studio. It could be that Xamarin Studio has some bugs or maybe you are doing something wrong, I can't tell, I don't use Xamarin Studio.